# builtins.True syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean, built-in

Why does the following code generate a syntax error?

```
>>> import builtins

>>> dir(builtins)
['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', 'AttributeError', 'BaseException', 'BlockingIOError', 'BrokenPipeError', 'BufferError', 'BytesWarning', 'ChildProcessError', 'ConnectionAbortedError', 'ConnectionError', 'ConnectionRefusedError', 'ConnectionResetError', 'DeprecationWarning', 'EOFError', 'Ellipsis', 'EnvironmentError', 'Exception', 'False', 'FileExistsError', 'FileNotFoundError', 'FloatingPointError', 'FutureWarning', 'GeneratorExit', 'IOError', 'ImportError', 'ImportWarning', 'IndentationError', 'IndexError', 'InterruptedError', 'IsADirectoryError', 'KeyError', 'KeyboardInterrupt', 'LookupError', 'MemoryError', 'NameError', 'None', 'NotADirectoryError', 'NotImplemented', 'NotImplementedError', 'OSError', 'OverflowError', 'PendingDeprecationWarning', 'PermissionError', 'ProcessLookupError', 'ReferenceError', 'ResourceWarning', 'RuntimeError', 'RuntimeWarning', 'StopIteration', 'SyntaxError', 'SyntaxWarning', 'SystemError', 'SystemExit', 'TabError', 'TimeoutError', 'True', 'TypeError', 'UnboundLocalError', 'UnicodeDecodeError', 'UnicodeEncodeError', 'UnicodeError', 'UnicodeTranslateError', 'UnicodeWarning', 'UserWarning', 'ValueError', 'Warning', 'ZeroDivisionError', '_', '__build_class__', '__debug__', '__doc__', '__import__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'abs', 'all', 'any', 'ascii', 'bin', 'bool', 'bytearray', 'bytes', 'callable', 'chr', 'classmethod', 'compile', 'complex', 'copyright', 'credits', 'delattr', 'dict', 'dir', 'divmod', 'enumerate', 'eval', 'exec', 'exit', 'filter', 'float', 'format', 'frozenset', 'getattr', 'globals', 'hasattr', 'hash', 'help', 'hex', 'id', 'input', 'int', 'isinstance', 'issubclass', 'iter', 'len', 'license', 'list', 'locals', 'map', 'max', 'memoryview', 'min', 'next', 'object', 'oct', 'open', 'ord', 'pow', 'print', 'property', 'quit', 'range', 'repr', 'reversed', 'round', 'set', 'setattr', 'slice', 'sorted', 'staticmethod', 'str', 'sum', 'super', 'tuple', 'type', 'vars', 'zip']
>>> builtins.True
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    builtins.True
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know in Python 3.X `True` and `False` are reserved words, but calling `builtins.True` am I just calling an attribute on the module object `builtins`?

Comment: you can use `True` and `False` just as they are, no `builtins` module prefix is needed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`True` is  a reserved keyword, and that means you cannot use it as an attribute name either. Like names, attributes must be valid Python identifiers.

You can still access the object as an attribute with `getattr()`:

```
>>> import builtins
>>> getattr(builtins, 'True')
True
```

This can be found in the documentation under:

- [*Attribute references*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#attribute-references) in the expression documentation:

  ```
  attributeref ::=  primary "." identifier
  ```
- [*Identifiers and keywords*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) in the lexical analysis docs:

  > The following identifiers are used as reserved words, or *keywords* of the language, and **cannot be used as ordinary identifiers**.
  >
  > `False` [...] `True`

  Emphasis mine.

Comment: ok, so, being `True` and `False` now reserverd words they aren't lookedup in the builtins module, is it right?

Comment: @antox: `True` and `False` are literals and loaded as constants with the bytecode. They are built-in singletons, just like `None` is.

Comment: but are they taken from the builtins module?

Comment: @antox: of course they are. The `builtins` module is just a series of names letting you address built-in objects. But because `None` and `True` and `False` are keywords the compiler can store them as constants because nothing can ever rebind those names to something else.

Comment: @antox: the language definition is that these are singletons and the names are keywords, so they cannot be anything *but* built-in objects.